# How can I merge several logical volumes into a new logical volume on another disk online? Bonus curveball, all the lv's are /var folders

Tags: redhat, lvm

I have two virtual disks `sda` and `sdb` on an rhel7 VM.  My `/var` and `/var/log` folders are both constrained by the sizes of their initial provisioned `logical volumes`.

`sda` is partitioned into an xfs filesystem: `/dev/sda1` mounted at `/boot` and a *physical volume*: `/dev/sda2` named `rhel`.
There is a *volume group*: `rhel` with several *logical volumes*, specifically the ones of concern to this question are mounted at `/var`, `/var/log`, `/var/log/audit/` and `/var/tmp`.

The disk `sdb` is new and I was thinking of creating a single pv/vg out of the drive and moving `/var`, `/var/log` and `/var/log/audit/` (keeping `/var/tmp` on it's own lvm on `sda2`) to it.

1. Would it just be better/possible to just grow the current *logical volumes* from space allocated from the new disk, if so, how does that work?
2. Is there a good reason NOT to just have `/var`, `/var/log` and `/var/log/audit/` on the same *logical volume*?
3. Is there a way to do this online, meaning this is a web server and I would like to have it continue serving?
4. If this is unable to be done online, what steps would I need to take to reboot into a mode I can ssh into the server but no other services running that would prevent me from unmounting/moving the `/var` folder's contents?

Comment: Please add output of pvs;vgs;lvs

Comment: Of you are using Logical volume management, and don't intend to shrink the volume back in the future this can, I believe, be done online without a reboot.  (I have not grown an xfs volume, but have done this kind of thing often with ext4 volumes)